# How do I link from one view to another when using aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I have tried using the normal links that would work in a basic mvc project, as well as links similar to what I see in the pages the views but I seems to be getting an error that is only resolved when I add the view as a menu item on the MainMenu, which is not what I want to do. There must be a way around this...

I have a page, 'WorkOrders' (workorders/index), which displays a list of Work Orders. There's a link for creating a new work order, which should go to the 'Create' (workorders/create, I'll also need to get workorders/create/customerid working) page.

```
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
```

and

```
<a href="/workorders/create">Create New</a>
```

both generate an error when clicked:

```
Unhandled exception at line 127, column 17 in 
http://localhost:62114/js/admin.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'offsetTop' of 
undefined or null reference
```

Where would I define 'offsetTop'? Is there some other way to solve this error? I'm guessing that if I try to hack it away I'll just get another error to deal with and was hoping to resolve it correctly.

Does this mean it's trying to load this view inside of the shared layout that requires that value to be defined somewhere? I don't see any difference between workorders/index and workorders/create except workorders/index being on the MainMenu.

I see the pages that come with the template as examples all have their own js files, do I need to create similar js files for all of the views I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create js files for all of the views you add.

Change this in [`admin.js`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/c4959409ab385f6d2832c0299692cbcacc8bab1a/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/wwwroot/js/admin.js#L127-L128):

```
var activeItemOffsetTop = $('.menu .list li.active')[0].offsetTop
if (activeItemOffsetTop > 150) $el.slimscroll({ scrollTo: activeItemOffsetTop + 'px' });
```

to this:

```
var $activeItem = $('.menu .list li.active')[0];
if ($activeItem.length) {
    var activeItemOffsetTop = $activeItem.offsetTop;
    if (activeItemOffsetTop > 150) $el.slimscroll({ scrollTo: activeItemOffsetTop + 'px' });
```

This is required to handle pages without its own menu item on the main menu.

Comment: I was able to add that code but am still getting the same error. When the debugger hits that line in the admin.js file and shows it to me the code I wrote is not loading. Also, the file name is loading as admin.js[virtual], do I need to put an explicit link to that file to solve this part?

Comment: Oh boy, wow, thanks! Ok, not I'm getting a different error. 

    Unhandled exception at line 136, column 17 in 
    http://localhost:62114/js/admin.js
    0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' 
    of undefined or null reference

So I don't think that code worked. Maybe I haven't created the view properly?

Comment: I got it to work but only by commenting out the code that was complaining in admin.js. Not a long term solution but it doesn't seem to have broken anything else yet and now I can resume building my views. I will keep working on my view now and try to fix this part later.

Comment: Well, you need to say what's on line 136.